# Get Google Maps API search with Zip Code

Tags: ajax, google-maps, laravel, google-maps-api-3

I need to make a search of tailors based on the Zip Code given by the user. Im working on the Laravel Framework (Version 5)
I can successfully retrieve the results via Ajax but I have problems trying to manage them with json.

This is my url: 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=coppel+64710&key=AIzaSyBwb9nwAYMYm4cBkGzAFHmVeqwwoAQEIjI&sensor=true

This is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 8
      });
   }

   $(document).ready(function() { 
      //the button that activates the search search
      $("#find-tailor").click(function() {
         $.ajax({
            url:  'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=tailor+78577&key=AIzaSyBwb9nwAYMYm4cBkGzAFHmVeqwwoAQEIjI&sensor=true',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: 'callback'

        }).done(function(data) {
               console.log(data);
            });             
      });
   });
</script>

//The script to inicializate the map
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB-amPYw4EvJGyYfY16HzhF2lqpw--FcHM&libraries=places&callback=initMap">  </script>
```

This is the error I get

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

However, if you enter to the url, it has json values
How can I manage to get them?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using Google Places Java script API , the way you are calling is wrong.

Please check the example at [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search#try-it-yourself)